# Values in array are all same

Tags: java

Getting value of `k` right every time, but values in the array `m[l]` in the last for-loop are all same.

```
int l,j,k=0;
int m[]=new int[10];
for(l=0;l<len;l++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        char a= sub.charAt(j);
        k=k*100+(int)a;
    }
    System.out.println("k=" +k);
    m[l]=k;
    System.out.println(m[l]);
}
for(l=0;l<len;l++)
    System.out.println("outside all loop m[l] = " +m[l]);
```

Comment: Please indent your code first.

Comment: What are the values of `sub` and `len`?

Comment: sub is the substring of a String and len is the no. of substrings.

Comment: here I am taking one substring at a time, and character by character finding its integer value and adding all values of the substring together

Comment: I'm afraid that whoever taught you to declare variables like that, shouldn't be teaching computer programming. There are so many bugs that can arise from incorrectly scoped variables and all popular languages support sensible scoping.

Comment: your second for-loop does the same thing everytime(so k will have the same value), and at every loop you're asigning k to m[l]. What are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: but my values of 'k' and 'm[l]' are different for each iteration in the nested loops,  but in last 'for-loop' the values of m[l] are all same as last value of 'k'

Comment: @Makoto even if you declare it like that, in the second loop `l` will be reasigned asigned value 0. Although its not pretty, it should "fire".

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I misread that.  I blame my new contacts.

Comment: @user3638271 are you sure you're running the same code you provided us? I'm pretty sure your `k` should have the same value at every println

Comment: actually 'sub' here is a substring of a String of length 10,

Comment: Using "l" ("ell") as a variable name is pure, unadulterated evil. Upper case "oh" is just as bad!

Comment: I am using an outer loop to get the substrings of length from the string, so 'sub' should be different for every loop

Comment: ohh,,, now I get it,, the values are all same for sub

Comment: hey, can anyone help me with this??????????
I have to take a String, form its substrings of length 10,
and then for each substring I have to find 'k' using the same formula and save value that we get from each substring into a array of integer

Answer (score 0):

This line accomplished nothing the first 9 times it runs in the inner loop:

```
k=k*100+(int)a;
```

Its value is just set by the last run of the inner loop, which is when `m[l]` gets set also. Fixing that should help with whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement was a bit fuzzy but looks like changing k to long would do the trick.

```
long k = 0;
int l, j = 0;
long m[]=new long[10];
```

Comment: See,,
I have to take a String, form its substrings of length 10,
and then for each substring I have to find 'k' using the same formula and save value that we get from each substring into a array of integer.
can u help me with that?

Comment: It would be easier someone to help you out if you can provide more complete code with some test data. Too much guessing with original one.